# How to install mongo db extension in hostgator VPS?

Tags: mongodb, centos

I have a VPS hosting account with hostagator. 
They mentioned mongodb support is available in VPS/Dedicated account see this

http://support.hostgator.com/articles/pre-sales-questions/compatible-technologies.

Unfortunately some of modules we only have to install. I did contact the hostgator customer care also, but they replied the same thing.

The server config is:

OS:  CENTOS 5.8 x86_64 virtuozzo

Web Server: Apache

So how to install mongodb extension in hostgator linux based VPS account?

Comment: So what the problem? Use shell access to your server and install mongodb.

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat-centos-or-fedora-linux/

Comment: "Important Notice: This page does not imply that we install these programs for free. Some programs on this list are already on the server or can be installed for free, but some of these programs require installation or administrative fees."

Comment: how to login into shell .... ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got an email from hostgator. they told like they will install mongodb for 35$. But now i will tell u the easy solution.

Step1: login into shell 
Read this: 
  http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/lets-get-started/how-do-i-get-and-use-ssh-access

Step2: 
  http://lancegatlin.org/tech/centos-6-install-mongodb

I have only followed these two steps...

Comment: you are telling me the mongod instance has to be started on your machine all the time to make it work?

Comment: u have to run the mongod instance... u can start when u need or u can add it into the os startup....